# First section title font size needs to be increase by using xslt

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

In my xml having three sections titles, all are in h1 position, But i want the first section as h1 position and remaning has to be h2 positions and my xml file is

```
<section>
         <title>DESCRIPTION</title>
         <p>The A380 is available with two types of turbofan engines, the
Rolls-Royce Trent 900 (variants A380-841, −842 and −843F) or the Engine
Alliance GP7000 (A380-861 and −863F).  Noise reduction was an important
requirement in the A380 design, and particularly affects engine design.</p>
         <p>Landing gears<ul>
               <li>
                  <p>Nose Landing Gear</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>Wing Landing Gear (Bogie Type, 4 Wheels  - 4 Braked)</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>Body Landing Gear (Bogie Type, 6 Wheels  - 4 Braked)</p>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </p>
      </section>
      <section>
         <title>Wing Landing Gear</title>
         <p>Each wing landing gear has a leg assembly and
a four-wheel bogie beam. The WLG leg includes a Bogie Trim Actuator
(BTA) and an oleo-pneumatic shock absorber.</p>
      </section>
      <section>
         <title>Body Landing Gear</title>
         <p>The two body landing gears have a six-wheel bogie
beam and a leg assembly that includes an oleo- pneumatic shock absorber.
A two-piece drag-stay assembly mechanically locks the leg in the extended
position.</p>
         <fig>
            <title>Landing gear</title>
            <image align="center" href="../ICN-HSXWB-A-791111-H-F0302-00001-A-001-01.tif"/>
         </fig>
      </section>
```

Im using the xslt as

```
  <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' topic/section ')][@spectitle != ''
                         and not(*[contains(@class, ' topic/title ')])]"
    mode="dita2xslfo:section-heading"
    priority="10">
    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="section.title">
      <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
      <xsl:variable name="spectitleValue" as="xs:string" select="string(@spectitle)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="resolvedVariable">
        <xsl:call-template name="insertVariable">
          <xsl:with-param name="theVariableID" select="$spectitleValue"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:sequence
        select="if (not(normalize-space($resolvedVariable)))
        then $spectitleValue
        else $resolvedVariable"
      />
    </fo:block>

<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' topic/section ')]">
        <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="section">
            <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="dita2xslfo:section-heading"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
```

Please guide me regarding this. Thank you

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean by "But i want the first section itself font to be high than the other section title's" and where the problem lies. Your code `contains(@class,' topic/section ')` does not make sense, there is no @class attribute in your xml and if there were, why should it contain **space** topic/section **space**?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `contains(@class,' topic/section ')` means that @BoopathyChandran uses DITA and he is developing the PDF plug-in stylesheet.

Comment: Yes absoulutely. You got it tmakita. U having any idea in this

Comment: By the way, what DITA-OT version are you using?

Comment: DITA 1.8.5 version

Answer (score 0):

This is minimum template that I can send.

- I found your first template does not match any `section` element because all of the your input XML file section elements have title element.
- Instead I added two xsl:attribute-set for H1 and H2 and apply them based section element position.

  ```
  <xsl:attribute-set name="section.title.h1" use-attribute-sets="section.title">
      <xsl:attribute name="font-size">20pt</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="section.title.h2" use-attribute-sets="section.title">
      <xsl:attribute name="font-size">12pt</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/section ')]">
      <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="section">
          <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
          <!--xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="dita2xslfo:section-heading"/-->
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/section ')]/*[contains(@class, ' topic/title ')]">
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="empty(parent::*/preceding-sibling::*[contains(@class, ' topic/section ')])">
              <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="section.title.h1">
                  <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates/>
              </fo:block>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
              <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="section.title.h2">
                  <xsl:call-template name="commonattributes"/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates/>
              </fo:block>
          </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  ```

Probably you want to do more complex transformation, but I hope this example helps your development.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [position()](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_position.html) function to achieve this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
            <!--attributes for H1 go here-->
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size">24</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!--attributes for H2 go here-->
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size">18</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```